# delphi type info of object

Tags: delphi, object, types, typeinfo

I have code like below

```
 TLivingThing=class
 end;

 THuman=class(TLivingThing)
 public
   Language:String
 end;

 TAnimal=class(TLivingThing)
 public
   LegsCount:integer;
 end;


 procedure GetLivingThing()
 var
   livingThing:TLivingThing;
 begin
   livingThing:=THuman.Create();
   if livingThing=TypeInfo(THuman) then ShowMessage('human');

   livingThing:=TAnimal.Create();
   if livingThing=TypeInfo(TAnimal) then ShowMessage('animal');
 end;
```

1. how can I check type of object like above code? I tried typeInfo but message never executed
2. How can I access child class public field? just like this?

> TAnimal(livingThing).LegsCount=3;

its type safe-fashion? or any better way to accomplish this case?

thanks for sugestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
procedure GetLivingThing();
var
  livingThing:TLivingThing;
  human:THuman;
  animal:TAnimal;
begin
  livingThing:=THuman.Create();
  try

    if livingThing is THuman then
    begin
      human:=livingThing as THuman;
      ShowMessage('human');
    end;

    if livingThing is TAnimal then
    begin
      animal:=livingThing as TAnimal;
      ShowMessage('animal');
    end;

  finally
    livingThing.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: but how about public field on class? can I assigned like code on my question?

Comment: I might upvote this if it wasn't a code-only answer. Your answer would be a lot better if, instead of making everybody guess, you would spend a few words on where your code differs from the OP's and why that makes it work.

Comment: @navirius, in your example you are making a hard cast (TAnimal(livingThing).LegsCount). This is an unsafe cast. To catch errors at runtime, use (livingThing as TAnimal).LegsCount. See http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2007/qt/is_as_cast.htm for more information.

Answer (score -1):

Operator is sometimes misleads. In your case all is ok because classes which are checked are from last row of hierarchy. But your hierarchy isn't correct. Let consider following example (how many ifs will be executed?):

```
TLivingThing = class
end;
TAnimal = class(TLivingThing)
end;
THuman = class(TAnimal)
end;
TWolf = class(TAnimal)
end;

procedure Check;
var 
   a: THuman;
begin
a := THuman.Create;
if a is TLivingThing then 
   begin
   MessageBox('TLivingThing');
   //Do something useful here
  end;
if a is TAnimal then 
   begin
   MessageBox('TAnimal');  
   //Do something useful here  
   end;
if a is THuman then 
   begin
   MessageBox('THuman');
   //Do something useful here
   end;
end;
```

In this example you receive:
TLivingThing
TAnimal
THuman

If you wanted call only one if, you are wrong. Better solution is use

```
if a.ClassName = TLivingThing.ClassName then ...
if a.ClassName = TAnimal.ClassName then ...
if a.ClassName = THuman.ClassName then ...
```

In this case proper if will be called. This is very important if you use in if chain ancestors and descendants.

Comment: That is in no way a better solution, it is way more resource intensive. In your case, order the if's properly and then use "else if".